# Is there a way to create an account-contact relationship on object creation?

Tags: account, contact, standard-objects

I am trying to have the ability to create an account-contact relationship on account creation. I know you can establish this connection by using related lists, and after account creation I can go to the related tab and establish connection, but I want to be able to do this at the same time as creation of the account object. Can you create an account-contact relationship on object creation? Or is this not attainable today. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like using a trigger or a flow to add a `Contact` record? If so, where are you going to get the information from to create that contact? A screen flow might be what you're looking for. Also, be careful in your terminology in this particular situation. `AccountContactRelation` is a separate thing (that you need to enable the "allow contacts to be related to multiple accounts" feature for) with a significant difference in how you'd implement/approach this.

Comment: Okay that is helpful, I think a screen flow would solve this problem. I was really just wondering if there is an out of the box solution with adding related lists to a record creation page layout. I wanted to create a related contact to an account at the same time of account creation. Thank you for your feedback.